# How can you make the footer axapta reporting tool print at the bottom of the page?

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to print something at the bottom of a report.  I am using a section `Pagefooter`.
I thought that if you used `Pagefooter` that it would print at the bottom on the report.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Pagefooter section to display footer at the end of page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to print the sum of field in the column, use `sum all` property in properties node. Displaying in footer has a disadvantage that if report exceeds more than one page, every page on report will get printed.